# Opening Page in IE using Java & Getting Confirmation on its load

Tags: java, browser, desktop-application

I want to load a URL in the user's default browser. And once the webpage gets loaded completely I want to take its screenshot.

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String x[]) throws Exception
    {
        Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
        URI oURL = new URI("http://192.168.1.125:8001/html/en/default/process/ProcessDesigner.jsp?wftId=81454277&wftVersion=1");
        desktop.browse(oURL);
        desktop.wait();

        //desktop.print("");
        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
        ImageIO.write(capture, "jpg", new File("E:\\Akram\\SSFolder\\fi2.jpg"));
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Here I am using the `sleep` function so that I should be able to capture snapshot after screen gets loaded, but some web pages may take longer to load.

So I want confirmation that the web page is ready / loaded completely so that I can take its snapshot.

How can I achieve this?